# Why Does Mongoose Query Return an Empty Array

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello I have looked at similar questions to the one I asked but none of the resolutions fit my issue.  I am developing an API.

I get the request payload from client and a response payload on the server side when I send response using payload, it's when I try to use a mongoose query(search) that I run into an issue with an empty array.  All things checkout such as:

Connected to mongoose,
Database does exist,
Collection exist and has default name of my interface/class.

To be assured I had the correct db name I let it be created when I did `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database` for first time

My mongoose schema file exists. It takes on the default name on the class and it is singular. I have included a small snippet.  Can someone help tell me what I'm doing wrong,

Interface

```
export interface Products{
  _id: string,
  name: string
}
//imported in my service.ts
```

livesearch.js
Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema, 'products');
```

product.js

```
router.post('/getProducts',  async(req, res) =>{
      
    let payload=req.body.payload;//server needs to extract payload property
     console.log("Payload", payload);
       
    console.log("Heading to search");
    let search = await Products.find({name: {$regex: new RegExp('^'+payload+'.*',
   'i')}}).exec();
          console.log("Search", search) empty array
     //Limit search to 10
       search = search.slice(0, 10);

       //res.send({payload:load});  //this works
     
       res.send({payload:search});  
    
     
})
```

Database and collection

```
> show collections
productLiveSearch
products
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection likely doesn't have anything in it; you need to populate it first for a query to return with values.

Comment: Hello there is data in my db I did a find() from command line in mongoose and it showed me data